# How to debug WiFi problem on laptop with Linux (Fedora)?

Tags: fedora, wifi, debugging, laptop

I am using Fedora 31 (upgraded from 30, but the problem occured on 30 also) on my Dell Latitude 3580. Everything is working fine, but from time to time my network connection stops working. Pings are not working, websites not loading. What usually helps is turning WiFi off (in the upper right menu in the Gnome 3) and on, and waiting for it to reconnect with the network. It happens with multiple networks, not just my home router, but I believe but only with networks 5GHz, I don't have a problem with 2.4GHz. I don't have Windows installed along Fedora, so I don't know if it's hardware problem of software, with Linux.

How can I debug it? Where I can start? I feel like I don't know much about tools that would help me debug linux and WiFi network card in my laptop. Should I check driver's version, use some terminal commands that would help to identify if the problem is with hardware layer or system notices some kind of problem when the network fails? As of now I found something like this in `dmesg` during last time the problem occured (censored MAC):

```
[ 3101.338801] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from ac:22:05:XX:YY:ZZ by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 3104.954335] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: UART prints enabled
[ 3105.022917] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[ 3113.070526] wlp3s0: authenticate with ac:22:05:XX:YY:ZZ
[ 3113.137160] wlp3s0: send auth to ac:22:05:XX:YY:ZZ (try 1/3)
[ 3113.163946] wlp3s0: authenticated
[ 3113.164107] wlp3s0: associate with ac:22:05:XX:YY:ZZ (try 1/3)
[ 3113.200527] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from ac:22:05:XX:YY:ZZ (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
[ 3113.265490] wlp3s0: associated
[ 3113.307848] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[ 3386.045128] perf: interrupt took too long (3205 > 3202), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 62000
```

so it seems like it deauthenticated and then authenticated but the network is not working.

I don't have any problem with cabled ethernet connections.

Comment: What is the exact model of your wireless card?

Comment: Running `lspci | grep -i wireless` returns


```03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)```


Also, I discovered that the problem probably does not exist with 2.4GHz networks, only with 5GHz. At least that's what I've observed (I updated the questions and mentioned it there).